# Embedding of SOAP-UI project structure with Java projects in SVN

Tags: java, soapui

We are going to use SOAP-UI in our project to test our APIs. The API:s are implemented in Java and we use SVN. Since SOAP-UI tests go hand-in-hand with both the actual API Java implementation, and its version, I was wondering what would be the best way to structure the SOAP-UI tests?

1) Should each set of SOAP-UI tests for a Java project be a SOAP-UI Project or a Test Suite?
2) Would it make sense to include the SOAP-UI tests inside each Java project in the same way we usually embed JUnit tests (in its own package)?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, and will probably get closed as off-topic. My opinion: I do this all the time. Set everything up as a Maven project, put all SoapUI stuff in `src/test/soapui` directory. Run the soapui-maven-plugin in the integration-test phase.

Comment: Just to be clear, so you have one full SOAP-UI project inside each separate Java project? So the SOAP-UI project is not some separate branch in your SVN?

Comment: Correct. When the code branches (new version, new features, ...) the tests go with it! This makes it "Agile-correct", assuming that is even a thing.